# Can I get a US visa while visiting Germany?

Tags: visas, usa, germany, algerian-citizens

Can you get a visa to the US if you are in another country as a visitor? For example, you're from Algeria and visiting Germany. Are you allowed to apply for a visa at a US Embassy or Consulate in Germany?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can apply for a US visa at one of the _American_ consulates **in** Germany?

Comment: I'm asking if either the German Embassy or a US Embassy in Germany would issue or let you apply for a US Visa even though you don't live in Germany

Comment: I have no experience of that combination but I have of similar cases.  Person with nationality A wants a visa to B while in C.  In the cases, I have seen, it is possible but slow.  The embassy in C sent the application to its embassy in A (not B) for review.  It seemed that it was common that the list of undesirable citizens of A was maintained by the embassy in A.  My experiences are quite old and modern computerised systems may have helped but I would not be surprised if it is still slow.

Comment: There are no German consulates in Germany. Did you mean US consulate located in Germany?

Comment: I am not sure what it would be called in Germany.. consulate, embassy, mission...

Comment: If you are in Germany and want a visa to the US then your first point of call should be a US embassy or consulate in Germany.  Countries do not have embassies in their own countries e.g. there is no German embassy in Germany but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do it in all countries. However, I know that, for example, Brazilians can get US visa in Uruguay. It happens b/c there is not a place to get US Visa in South of Brazil and Montevideo is near than São Paulo if you leave in Porto Alegre, for example.

Comment: I don't know about the US embassy in Berlin, but the UK embassy in Berlin **does not give out visas**. There is no consulate office there. They probably do not do this because (for now) Germans (and other Schengen residents) do not need a visa. They can just come to the UK with a simple border control. So there is no need to give out visas. If you want to apply for a UK visa in Berlin, there is a private company that helps with doing the application and does the transport to and from the UK of your passport. Beware that when they say something is optional, you should supply it anyway.

Comment: @simbabque I don't understand.  What does this have to do with US visas? 
(Furthermore, there must be at least tens of thousands of foreigners living in Germany who *are* visa nationals in the UK, so there *is* a need to give out visas.)

Comment: @phoog it's related in a way that it's not always possible to get a visa at an embassy in a different country. It's not the US, but it's at least something to think about, so I figured sharing doesn't hurt. And yes, there is a need. But the process to use this third party company thing works. Unless you don't include optional documents about which the form says they will ask for them if they need them, which they didn't, and then you get rejected.

Comment: @simbabque but the UK does issue visas to applicants who are in Germany without being residents of Germany. The fact that the visas are not processed in the embassy is immaterial.

Comment: @phoog they do, but not directly. You go through a third party. It takes long. And you need to find out where first because the embassy might just say we do not do it here.

Answer (score 3):

The US missions in Germany don't make this information readily available on [their visa pages](https://de.usembassy.gov/visas/), but the US policy is nicely expressed by [the US Embassy in Thailand](https://th.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/non-immigrant-visas-frequently-asked-questions/):

> I am a citizen of another country who would like to apply for a visa while in Thailand. Can I do so?
>
> While it is the policy of U.S. Embassy Bangkok to accept visa applications from anyone physically present in our consular district, we strongly recommend that you make your application in your country of nationality or residence. Should you choose to apply in Bangkok, and you are not a Thai citizen or a long-term resident of Thailand, it may be quite difficult for the adjudicating consular officer to make a determination regarding your case. Additionally, while many visas are able to be issued within 3-4 business days of the interview, if there are any delays it could have a significant impact on the timing of your return travel.

So, the answer to your question is *yes,* you can get a visa to the US if you are visiting another country, but the application might take longer than it would if you applied in your country of residence, and the probability of success may be lower.

---

It has become apparent in the comments that you intend to marry the visa applicant in the US:

> My friend has applied in his country, Algeria, and has been denied both times. They keep saying it's because they think he wants to marry. The last time he went they told him do not apply again for 3 years... I am at a loss for what to do to help him. – GIGI SMITH
>
> @GIGISMITH applying in Germany won't help overcome the factors that led to the refusals in Algeria. – phoog
>
> Thank you phoog. I am just at a loss at how to help. I guess we will try a fiance visa since this is what they believe. – GIGI SMITH
>
> @GIGISMITH are you in fact going to marry? – phoog
>
> Yes. We wanted to meet and come back to US for marriage. We do not think they will accept this either. It is just difficult to get his visa. He has tried twice in the past 8 months but only trying tourist visa. – GIGI SMITH

If the intention is to settle in the US, then the previous visa refusals were correct because a tourist visa is the wrong visa for that purpose. If that is your intention, however, the question is off topic here; you should ask instead at [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

If the intention is to leave the US after you marry, then you should be up front about your intentions.  In that case you will need compelling evidence of concrete plans to build a life outside the US.  This is necessary because the law requires applicants for nonimmigrant visas to overcome a presumption that they intend to immigrate.

Another option would be to get married in another country and then apply for an immigrant visa as the spouse of a US citizen (assuming you are in fact a US citizen).

Finally, you may have created a bit of trouble for yourself already, however, since referring to someone you intend to marry as a "friend" can seem deceptive.  Applying for a fiance visa after two refused tourist visa applications could call your credibility into question.  If you can afford one, now is probably the time to engage a reputable immigration lawyer.

Comment: That matches my experience of visa applications while not in your own country: possible but maybe much slower.  It is not always the case, I have seen some cases in which the process was quick but you cannot rely on that.

Comment: USA visa application are decided within seconds by the interviewing officer. Why would it take longer with an application in another country?

Comment: @greatone: That's just the *interview* part. They also need to take time to review your application first.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill do you have any sources to back that up?

Comment: @greatone the decision isn't always made in seconds. See for example https://pennstatelaw.psu.edu/sites/default/files/documents/pdfs/Immigrants/Administrative-Processing-FAQ.pdf

Comment: @phoog administrative processing is required in less than 1% of cases, mostly related to security grounds and isn't relevant in the OP's case. The applicant is usually told his visa is approved pending security clearance.

Comment: @greatone how can you know that administrative processing isn't relevant to the OP's case? She hasn't even applied yet.  Furthermore, the question was asked in general terms. The state department says that applying in a consulate in whose district the applicant does not reside can result in delays.  Even if that's true for just one case in a thousand, it's still true.

Comment: My friend has applied in his country, Algeria, and has been denied both times. They keep saying it's because they think he wants to marry. The last time he went they told him do not apply again for 3 years... I am at a loss for what to do to help him.

Comment: @GIGISMITH applying in Germany won't help overcome the factors that led to the refusals in Algeria.

Comment: Thank you phoog. I am just at a loss at how to help. I guess we will try a fiance visa since this is what they believe.

Comment: @GIGISMITH are you in fact going to marry?

Comment: Yes. We wanted to meet and come back to US for marriage. We do not think they will accept this either. It is just difficult to get his visa. He has tried twice in the past 8 months but only trying tourist visa.

Comment: @GIGISMITH please see the edited answer.

Comment: Phoog. It was the original intent to have him come visit the US first and later if agreed to make more permanent arrangements. We are now in over a year and choose to move forward in our relationship. However,  as said before we are not sure the right way to proceed. I am a US citizen born.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60989/discussion-between-phoog-and-gigi-smith).